# Validation of REST API with different input files each time

Tags: api, rest, file, postman

We have built REST API that takes input as a File, which provides the expected output/response content after server-end logic execution.

However we have hundreds of such input files, that we would like to validate and verify the result/output.

Could you pls let us know, is there any possibility that we can do this using script/post-man/any other tool, to choose/target a folder(which contains those input files) and does makes API call ?

Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for a test running / testing framework. There's plenty out there like Jest, PHPUnit (find a good one for your language of choice). I'd recommend against relying on Postman for anything. It's proprietary and more of a debugging tool.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/64954126/6793637

Check this answer on how to give a file path as variable.

now use data driven approach

```
filePATh 

c:/1
c:2
```